# is this possible to remove advertisement from my webview?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, ios9

Problem :
actually i am getting url link from api response. and by that link i am loading webview. but when webview load its also showing advertisement so is there any possible way to remove that ad from my webview?
here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: webviewurl)!
    let request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    myweb.loadRequest(request)
}
```

let me know if is there any possible way to remove ad from webview or may be from url

Comment: The ad came with webpage, so the only option is to manipulate DOM

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can't change the content of webview you get because what you actually get is a HTML file and then rendered as a webpage.

If the ad only exists in mobile phone, there may be a DNS hijacking,